# How to convert a DataTable in Cucumber to a List of objects?

Tags: java, cucumber

### Original Title: What does scalar mean in Cucumber DataTables in Java?

From [this](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=dJ_DXvFnIgoC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=scalar+fundamentals+java&source=bl&ots=iqGWFZYSy0&sig=hFkowfF15hv1WP6jB0j68G_vKco&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWy732gpjWAhXLLyYKHbrKBNoQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=scalar%20fundamentals%20java&f=false) reference:

> Java provides several scalar types. These include primitive numeric
>   types, plus boolean and char.
>
> Every scalar (primitive) type has an associated wrapper class or
>   reference type.

Reading the javadocs:

```
/**
  * Converts the table to a List.
  *
  * If {@code itemType} is a scalar type the table is flattened.
  *
  * Otherwise, the top row is used to name the fields/properties and the remaining
  * rows are turned into list items.
  *
  * @param itemType the type of the list items
  * @param <T>      the type of the list items
  * @return a List of objects
  */
public <T> List<T> asList(Class<T> itemType) {
    return tableConverter.toList(this, itemType);
}

/**
  * Converts the table to a List of List of scalar.
  *
  * @param itemType the type of the list items
  * @param <T>      the type of the list items
  * @return a List of List of objects
  */
public <T> List<List<T>>> asLists(Class<T> itemType) {
    return tableConverter.toLists(this, itemType);
}
```

However, I was able to pass String.class in asList():

```
List<String> list = dataTable.asList(String.class);
```

A String is not a primitive in Java. I would like some clarification on what "scalar" means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find an explicit definition about what Cucumber for Java means with `scalar type`.

The best hint I could find was in the snippet that is produced for new steps that accept a `DataTable`. The generated comment reads:

> For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
>   List<YourType>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>> or Map<K,V>.
>   E,K,V must be a scalar (String, Integer, Date, enum etc)

So it seems that besides the "Java scalar types" (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`, `boolean`, or respectively their wrapper types `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Char` and `Boolean`) you can also use `String`, `java.util.Date` and enum types.

Actually, a short test showed that I can use any type that has a constructor with a single `String` as parameter.

---

A small example with my own value class (very contrived). The output from the following snippets is a `List<List<MyValueClass>>`.

```
// MyValueClass.java
public class MyValueClass {

    private final String value;

    public MyValueClass(String v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

// snippet from MySteps.java
@Given("^a table with$")
public void a_table_with(DataTable arg1) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(arg1.asLists(MyValueClass.class));
}

// snippet from my test1.feature
  Scenario: Test with Datatable
    Given a table with
      | a | b | c |
      | 1 | 2 | 3 |
      | a | b | c |
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, might you provide a snippet in how you used the "any type with constructor that accepts String param" for `asList()` and `asLists()`?

Answer (score 9):

Quoting the generated code snippet:

```
// For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
// List<YourType>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>> or Map<K,V>.
// E,K,V must be a scalar (String, Integer, Date, enum etc)
```

"Scalar" from the Cucumber javadocs may have been incorrectly used to collectively mean the associated ***wrapper class*** of the primitives (i.e. scalar) among other things.

---

From below example, `asList()` proceeds to create a List of the user defined Expense object as per docs:

> Otherwise, the top row is used to name the fields/properties and the
>   remaining rows are turned into list items.

I have observed the following:

1. The top row (header) in the Feature file must *match* the field
   names of the object.
2. The constructor may accept all fields as parameters.

**User Defined Object (Non-Scalar):**

```
public class Expense {

    private String name = null;
    private String amount = null;
    private String frequency = null;

    public Expense(String name, String amount, String frequency) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**Feature:**

```
When I Enter My Regular Expenses
  | name        | amount | frequency     |
  | Electricity |   5500 | Monthly       |
  | Water       |    900 | Weekly        |
  | Internet    |   1900 | Every 2 Weeks |
  | Cable TV    |    555 | Daily         |
```

**Step Def:**

```
@When("^I Enter My Regular Expenses$")
public void I_Enter_My_Regular_Expenses(DataTable dataTable) throws Throwable {
  List<Expense> expenseList = dataTable.asList(Expense.class);

  for (Expense expense : expenseList) {
    System.out.println(expense);
  }

  // Here, asList() creates a List of Expense objects.
}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Only works until Cucumber-JVM 2.4.0. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771856/cucumber-jvm-io-cucumber-datatable-undefineddatatabletypeexception) for v3.x.x.

Comment: Thanks Lu, this looks like something I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For Lower Versions use the below implementation.

Datatable.feature

```
When Datatable to Pojo
 |  field1  |  field1Value1  | field1Value2  |
 |  field2  |  field2Value1  | field2Value2  |
 |  field3  |  field3Value1  | field3Value2  |
 |  field4  |  field4Value1  | field4Value2  |
 |  field5  |  field5Value1  | field5Value2  |
```

Pojo.class

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Pojo {

private String field1;
private String field2;
private String field3;
private String field4;
private String field5;

}
```

StepDefinition.class

```
@Given("Datatable to Pojo")
public void method (DataTable dataTable){
    List<Pojo> pojoList = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    List<Map<String,String>> mapList = dataTable.transpose().asMaps();
    for(Map<String, String> map : mapList) {
        pojoList.add(new ObjectMapper().convertValue(map, Pojo.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the argument as a List, but don’t define any capture groups in the expression:

If the Datatable contains only one column then Data Table is automatically flattened to a List by Cucumber (using DataTable.asList(String.class)) before invoking the step definition.

Comment: What cucumber version is this?