# Conversion of Cucumber DataTable to Map

Tags: cucumber-java

I am using Cucumber Data Tables. I want to convert this Data Table into a Map rather than a list.
So basically what if I use the Header Row as Key and the data rows as value for the key. 
How should I do that?

Let me share 1 example to be more clear.

Given the following animals:

```
  | Type  | BabyAnimal |    
  | cow   | Calf       |
  | horse | Pony       |
  | sheep | Lamb       |
```

Instead of creating a `List<List<String>>` here, it is a better approach to use  a `List<Map<String,String>>` here.
Map's Key should contain 'Type' and 'BabyAnimal' and values should contain the respective values.
So the Map entities would be:

```
<Type,cow>,<BabyAnimal,Calf>
<Type,horse>,<BabyAnimal,Pony>
<Type,sheep>,<BabyAnimal,Lamb>
```

How would we do that?
I feel this is a better approach of doing because we are fetching the data from the keys. 
eg `List(1).Map.get(Type)`
Whereas in case of List we would have to do a get(0), get(1) and there are chances of using incorrect data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using? (as there were some changes to DataTables in v3)

Answer (score 5):

And adding a second answer because the generic types in your question got munched by the html.

Given the following animals:

```
| Type  | BabyAnimal |    
| cow   | Calf       |
| horse | Pony       |
| sheep | Lamb       |
```

And assuming you want this to be your step definition:

```
@Given("all baby animal details")
public void allMapDetails(List<Map<String, String>> animals) {
    System.out.println(animals);
}
```

Then the table will be automatically converted to a list of maps of string to string.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the API has moved on since this question was first posted. I'm using cucumber version 4.8.1 and this code gives what you need without the cumbersome Lists of Maps

```
Map<String, String> map = dataTable.asMap(String.class, String.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Marit's answer, if you are on v3 plus you will need to work a bit more. Instead of a getting back a List of Maps, you can get back a custom object which contains the List of Maps.

Refer to this to figure out about a configuration class to mention all the datatable conversions - [Cucumber-JVM - io.cucumber.datatable.UndefinedDataTableTypeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771856/cucumber-jvm-io-cucumber-datatable-undefineddatatabletypeexception/50772199#50772199)

Place this bit of code into this class.

```
registry.defineDataTableType(new DataTableType(Animals.class, new TableTransformer<Animals>() {
            @Override
            public Animals transform(DataTable table) throws Throwable {
                Animals animals = new Animals();
                table.asMaps().forEach(e -> animals.addAnimal(e));
                return animals;
            }
        }));
```

---

This is the container or dataobject class.

```
public class Animals {

    public static final String type = "type";   
    public static final String baby = "babyanimal";

    private List<Map<String, String>> details = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addAnimal(Map<String, String> entry) {
        details.add(entry);
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animals [details=" + details + "]";
    }
}
```

---

Step definition

```
@Given("all baby animal details")
public void allMapDetails(Animals anim) {
    System.out.println(anim.getDetails());
}
```

---

You should get something like this -

> [{type=horse, babyanimal=Pony}, {type=sheep, babyanimal=Lamb},
>   {type=cow, babyanimal=Calf}]

Answer (score 2):

In Cucumber 3.0.2, just call asMaps() from DataTable.

```
public void feature_step(DataTable dataTable) {
    List<Map<String, String>> data =  dataTable.asMaps();
    String type = data.get(0).get("Type");
    Strig babyAnimal = data.get(0).get("BabyAnimal");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the following DataTable hint in the [cucumber-jvm project on GitHub](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/java/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/java/AbstractJavaSnippet.java):

```
        "    // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of\n" +
        "    // E, List<E>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>>, Map<K,V> or\n" +
        "    // Map<K, List<V>>. E,K,V must be a String, Integer, Float,\n" +
        "    // Double, Byte, Short, Long, BigInteger or BigDecimal.\n" +
        "    //\n" +
        "    // For other transformations you can register a DataTableType.\n";
```

You can find how, in the [Cucumber documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#data-tables):

The simplest way to pass a List to a step definition is to use a data table:

```
Given the following animals:
  | cow   |
  | horse |
  | sheep |
```

Declare the argument as a List, but don’t define any capture groups in the expression:

```
@Given("the following animals:")
public void the_following_animals(List<String> animals) {
}
```

In your case, replace `List` with `Map`.

Comment: With v3 this does require that there is a `TableEntryTransformer` that can create `Type` and `BabyAnimal`. If the top left cell is left blank a `TableCellTransformer` can also be used for `Type`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following animals:

```
| Type  | BabyAnimal |    
| cow   | Calf       |
| horse | Pony       |
| sheep | Lamb       |
```

And assuming you want this to be your step definition:

```
@Given("all baby animal details")
public void allMapDetails(Map<Type,BabyAnimal> animals) {
    System.out.println(animals);
}
```

When you define these paramter types:

```
public class ParameterTypes implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Locale locale() {
        return ENGLISH;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
        typeRegistry.defineDataTableType(new DataTableType(
            Type.class,
            (Map<String, String> row) -> new Type(row.get("Type"))
        ));

        typeRegistry.defineDataTableType(new DataTableType(
            BabyAnimal.class,
            (Map<String, String> row) -> new BabyAnimal(row.get("BabyAnimal"))
        ));
    }
}
```

Then the table will be converted to a map of animal type to baby animal.